# Automatically Relaunch Application On Crash?

Tags: c++, android, unit-testing, android-ndk

On Android, I'm running an application using the NDK that runs a series of tests in C++. If ever one of the tests fails, which most likely means a crash, I'd like the application to relaunch itself and start at the next test.

I wish I could use exceptions but the NDK doesn't support them.

Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but maybe @FlakyTest will cover that: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/FlakyTest.html But then again, it will probably only work with failing tests, not with errors that crash your app. But maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

1. Why does your application have to crash? Why not catch any exception being thrown? Even the compiler doesn't enforce you to add a try..catch block, [RuntimeExceptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) might still be thrown.
2. You can also use [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29). Note that this must be called per thread.
3. If, for some reason, the solutions above are not suitable for you, you could create a background service that acts as a [watchdog timer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer).

EDIT: Check [this link](http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk.php): for a custom version of the NDK that supports C++ exceptions. I found it in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/89db67ed1fbf6450).

Comment: I realized I forgot to mention that the tests are in C++, using the NDK. There are no exceptions in the NDK runtime, hence my problem.

Comment: As for 3, can a background service launch applications on its own?

Comment: Question was not about avoiding crash, but about relaunching app, so answer has to be subjective. I'm sure question author is doing his best to avoid crashes, huh?

Comment: Yes, simply call startActivity from the service.

Comment: Unfortunately, using an unsupported NDK isn't really an option.